# Convert XMLGregorianCalender to different timeZone

Tags: java, xml, calendar

Im tring to convert an XMLGregoriaCalnder to a specific timezome

Basically I receive a time from China through XML

```
<Date>2015-01-12</Date>
<Time>11:45:12</Time>
```

Unmarchall it

```
<Date>2015-01-12T11:45:12</Date>
```

Now I need to convert it to Newyork time before I insert it into the DB

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getDate(final XMLGregorianCalendar date) {

    TimeZone myzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    System.out.println(date + "..........");

    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();       
    calendar.setTimeZone(myzone);
    calendar.set(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(),
            date.getHour(), date.getMinute(), date.getSecond());

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = null;

    if (date != null) {
        try {
            xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar + "..........");

    return xmlGregorianCalendar;
}
```

Will output:

```
2014-01-10T11:45:12..........
2014-02-10T11:45:12.063-05:00....................
```

What I need to output:

```
2014-01-12T11:45:12..........
2014-01-11T21:45:12..........
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time difference is static between the originating time and your local time, so I'd try to simply add the time zone difference (13 hours) to the original time like this:

```
public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate(final XMLGregorianCalendar date, final XMLGregorianCalendar time) {

XMLGregorianCalendar date = null;
if (date != null && time != null) {
  try {
    newDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(),     date.getDay(),
    time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond(), time.getMillisecond(), 0);
    Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDurationDayTime(true, 0, 13, 0, 0);
    newDate.add(duration);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error creating date", e);
  }
}
return newDate;
```

Comment: Hey man...works a treat...Would it be possible to set a timezone??? or is there a safer way than hard coding the hours???...Again big thanks for the response...Ill mark as correct and up vote one iv enough reps

Comment: It is possible to set the timezone with the `XMLGregorianCalendar.setTimeZone()` call, see it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29).

Comment: Hey marczeeee, Iv updated my question. Iv been trying to implement the setTimeZone()...But I just cant get it to work...Keeps outputing the same time...arrrr

Comment: I have to take into account day light saving

Comment: Three things: you set timezone of `DateFormat`, but you don't use `df` anywhere. Second is that you get your `TimeZone` in a wrong way, check it [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html), you should use it like `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")`. Third thing is to set the timezone of the `calendar` variable and you'll get your date with a correct timezone.

Comment: Big thanks, Iv read the article and iv applied your feed back...Its concatenating the timezone to the end but I need the time to change??? Code updated